# Angular 2+ Developing Framework components

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I'm trying to develop some basic framework controls for an enterprise website where the developers could specify certain primitives types which get rendered consistency with minimal effort but still have the capacity to fully control the layout and content.  Each control would have the responsibility for defining style and maintaining some accessibility requirements. An analogy would be in a windows desktop application.  I can drag a GroupBox or Panel onto a form and set properties from the form, but then I can add controls and custom content to that panel without the panel needing to know about the content being placed.

So, as an example so far I have a Dashboard component and I want to place some tiles across the top of the screen and then a couple of panels.  One panel will have a Table displayed and the other panel will have a paragraph of text followed by a chart and the other will display some Tiles stacked vertically. I need to specify the framework control and where to place it but I'm unsure about how to pass the rich content or another configured component to be rendered in the `panel-body` div of my panel component.

**Dashboard template**
This defines a tile followed by some panels accepting properties which will be bound easily as these are known string values:

```
<h1 class="page-header">{{title}}</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <app-infra-tile headerText="Total Visitors" [mainText]="'0' | number" footerText="Some Text" icon="fa-users" colour="bg-blue"></app-infra-tile>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <app-infra-panel heading="Table Panel"></app-infra-panel>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <app-infra-panel heading="Graph Panel"></app-infra-panel>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <app-infra-panel heading="Some Panel"></app-infra-panel>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Tile Component and Template**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-infra-tile',
  templateUrl: './tile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tile.component.css']
})
export class TileComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() icon: string;
  @Input() headerText: string;
  @Input() mainText: string;
  @Input() footerText: string;
  @Input() colour = 'bg-blue';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
<div class="widget widget-stats {{colour}}">
  <div *ngIf="icon" class="stats-icon"><i class="fa {{icon}}"></i></div>
  <div class="stats-info">
      <div class="stats-title | uppercase">{{headerText}}</div>
      <div class="stats-number">{{mainText}}</div>  
      <div class="stats-desc">{{footerText}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Panel Component and Template**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-infra-panel',
  templateUrl: './panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.css']
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() htmlId: string;
  @Input() heading: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
<div class="panel panel-inverse" id="{{htmlId}}">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-heading-btn">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-success" data-click="panel-reload"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-warning" data-click="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-danger" data-click="panel-remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
    <h4 class="panel-title">{{heading}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    -----  The internal content managed by the dashboard should be rendered here  ----
  </div>
</div>
```

I've thought about passing in a service containing a factory method and in oninit of the Panel setting a local variable of type `any` to the result but then should the dashboard just implement that method to output raw html or can I pass another component instance through...  ??

Any advice is greatly appreciated.
I'm probably missing something really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [**Transclusion**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content) (Content Projection in NG2+) is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Barely viewed in a week but here's the answer a [colleague](https://prashantbrall.wordpress.com/) came up with.
The approach is using a Directive.  So given I have a Dashboard component I was to place a couple of panels on without having to write the Panel html repeatedly I do this in my DashboardComponent's template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <app-infra-panel heading="Some Panel" [componentName]="somePanelComponent"></app-infra-panel>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
    <app-infra-panel heading="Other Panel" [componentName]="otherPanelComponent"></app-infra-panel>
  </div>
</div>
```

`heading` is a property of the PanelComponent as well as `somePanelComponent` and `otherPanelComponent`. For every panel I intend to populate with some `Sub Component` I create a corresponding string for the component name.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class ProviderDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'The Dashboard';

  // Panel Content Component Names
  somePanelComponent = 'SomePanelComponent';
  otherPanelComponent = 'OtherPanelComponent';


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {    

  }

}
```

The PanelComponent being placed:

```
<div class="panel panel-inverse">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-heading-btn">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-success" data-click="panel-reload"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-warning" data-click="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-danger" data-click="panel-remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
    <h4 class="panel-title">{{heading}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div control-factory component="{{componentName}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>

import { Component, Input, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-infra-panel',
  templateUrl: './panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.css']
})
export class PanelComponent {

  @Input() heading: string;
  @Input() componentName: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

The `control-factory` Directive:

```
import {  Directive,
  Component,
  ComponentFactory,
  OnChanges,
  Input,
  ViewContainerRef,
  Compiler,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';

@Directive({
  selector: '[control-factory]'
})
export class ControlFactoryDirective implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {

  @Input() component: string;
  componentRef: any;
  init = false;
  factoryClass: any;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnChanges(): void {

    if (!this.component || this.init) return;

    var factories = Array.from(this.resolver['_factories'].keys());
    console.log(this.component);

    this.factoryClass = factories.find((x: any) => x.name === this.component);
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(this.factoryClass);
    const compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);


    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.destroy();
    }

    this.componentRef = compRef;
    this.init = true;
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.destroy();
      this.componentRef = null;
    }
  }
}
```

For each component being placed in the panels a Component needs to be created, in my case `SomePanelComponent` and `OtherPanelComponent`.  These need to be added to the `declarations` and `entryComponents` arrays in the App.module as well. I'm trying to work out how to place these in deeper modules in my project rather than having to place everything at the top level. So far no matter where I put them I get errors that they're not specified in the entryComponents array if it's not in App.module.

Anyway, I hope this is of value to anyone.